# Abbreviation Decoder Script in Java

Tags: java, compare

I am working on a program that is supposed to pull abbreviated text meanings from a list that is created from if-else statements. I am running into trouble with the logic of making the program see an incorrect input and provide a suggestion from the supported list. Here is the code we were given to edit.

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class TweetDecoder {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

      String origTweet = "";



      System.out.println("Enter abbreviation from tweet: ");

      origTweet = scnr.next();



      if (origTweet.equals("LOL")) {

         System.out.println("LOL = laughing out loud");

      }

      else if (origTweet.equals("BFN")) {

         System.out.println("BFN = bye for now");

      }

     else if (origTweet.equals("FTW")) {

         System.out.println("FTW = for the win");

      }

     else if (origTweet.equals("IRL")) {

        System.out.println("IRL = in real life");

      }

     else {

        System.out.println("Sorry, don't know that one.");

      }


     return;

   }

}
```

This is for a class so I would like to know if someone can push me in the right direction rather than give the full answer or the string that I should be using. I feel like is should be something to do with String Comparison or String Access Operations but I cant seem to get it nailed down. If someone can assist I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please clarify whats going wrong? You explain that it isn't working, but please give us what your output is and why its wrong, or explain how its failing.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but it would probably be a good idea using a `Map<String, String>` mapping abbreviations to their meaning.

Comment: Why do you have a `return` at the end?

Comment: I'd put the abbreviations in a properties file and eliminate the if/else logic.

Comment: @tobias_k I agree. I would also note that both the key and the origTweet strings be converted to all upper or all lower case.  If OP sticks with if statements, they should be using `String#equalsIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 0):

it wouldn't let me add a comment, so i suppose here will do.

I would suggest looking into the .startsWith method. Its a method contained in the String class.

For example,

```
if(origTweet.startsWith("L"))  //
  System.out.println("Perhaps you meant LOL");
```

sorry if this isn't what you meant / wanted